# Can I check for maintenance mode before redirecting to subdomain?

Tags: redirect, subdomains, cloudflare

I'm currently working on a site that will have several sub-domains that will need a re-direct based on country origin but the server doesn't have the `mod_geoip` module allowed so I can't use an `.htaccess` redirect, like:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

# Canada
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ca.abcd.com$1 [L]
```

I did some research and found that [Cloudflare](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-settings-get-ip-geolocation-setting) allows GEOlocation and I can use (code example):

```
$country_origin = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY']);
in a switch like (code is an example, hasn't been tested):

$country_origin = strtolower( $_SERVER[ "HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY" ] );
$clean_url = preg_replace("(^https?://)", "",  get_site_url() );
if ( !empty( $country_origin ) && $country_origin != 'us' ) {
  switch( $country_origin ) {
    case 'et';
        header( 'Location: http://' . $country_origin . '.' . $clean_url );
        break;          
    case 'us';
        header( 'Location: http://' . $country_origin . '.' . $clean_url );
        break;
    case 'ca';
        header( 'Location: http://' . $country_origin . '.' . $clean_url );
        break;
  }
}
```

Since each subdomain would have it's own WordPress installation as the content would be re-written and managed separately how can I check if the site is enabled in maintenance mode to stop/prevent the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time that WordPress inserts a blog into maintenance mode, it creates a file in the root of your installation directory.

the file contains a string related to the plugin/theme/core that is being updated. Its name is `.maintenance` (doesn't have a name, only extension).

The file stays there until the process is over, therefore you can check if the file exists by doing this:

```
if( file_exists(ABSPATH .'/.maintenance') ) { 
    // Stop redirection here
}
```

Which would be what you are looking for.